# BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type PhoneAuthenticationBloc. Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

I create blocs in a `MultiBlocProvider`, its child is a `BlocBuilder` that returns a `MultiBlocListener` but when sending an event

`BlocProvider.of<PhoneAuthenticationBloc>(context).add(VerifyPhoneNumberEvent(phoneNumber: controller.text.replaceAll(' ', '')));`

I get the `BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type PhoneAuthenticationBloc`, while other blocs work fine.

Can you spot what's wrong with `PhoneAuthenticationBloc()`?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<PhoneAuthenticationBloc>(
          create: (context) => PhoneAuthenticationBloc(userRepository: UserRepository()),
        ),
//        BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
//          create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: UserRepository()),
//          lazy: false,
//        ),
//        BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
//          create: (context) => UserBloc(),
//          lazy: false,
//        ),
        BlocProvider<BookingBloc>(
          create: (context) => BookingBloc(user: widget.user),
        ),
        BlocProvider<OrderBloc>(
          create: (context) => OrderBloc(user: widget.user),
        ),
        BlocProvider<PaymentBloc>(
          create: (context) => PaymentBloc(user: widget.user),
          lazy: false,
        ),
        BlocProvider<CartBloc>(
          create: (context) => CartBloc()..add(LoadCart()),
        ),
      ],
    child: BlocBuilder<PaymentBloc, PaymentState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is InitialStatePayment) {
            return MultiBlocListener(
                listeners: [
                  BlocListener<PhoneAuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
                    listener: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state){
...


FlatButton.icon(
                                    color: Colors.orange,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      print('pay pressed');
                                      print(
                                          'bookingStart is ${widget.bookingStart}, selected shop is ${widget.selectedShop}');
                                     if (isVerified == true){
                                       ...
                                     }
                                      else{
                                        showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          barrierDismissible: false,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context){
                                            return SingleChildScrollView(
                                              child: ValidatePhoneDialog(
                                                controller: controller,
                                                  onPressed: (){
                                                  if (controller.text.length >= 9){
                                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                                    showDialog(
                                                      context:context,
                                                      barrierDismissible: false,
                                                      builder: (BuildContext context){
                                                        return VerifyingDialog();
                                                      }
                                                    );
                                                    BlocProvider.of<PhoneAuthenticationBloc>(context).add(VerifyPhoneNumberEvent(phoneNumber: controller.text.replaceAll(' ', '')));
                                                  } else {
                                                    scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                                        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                                        content: Text(
                                                            AppLocalizations.instance
                                                                .text('Wrong number'),
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))));
                                                  }
                                                  }
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        );
                                     }



                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.payment,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    label: Text(
                                      AppLocalizations.instance.text('Pay'),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                                    )),
```

```
class PhoneAuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;


  PhoneAuthenticationBloc({@required UserRepository userRepository})
      : assert(userRepository != null),
        _userRepository = userRepository;

  String verificationId = "";


  @override
  AuthenticationState get initialState => Uninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
      AuthenticationEvent event) async* {
    // phone verification
    if (event is VerifyPhoneNumberEvent) {
      print('VerifyPhoneNumberEvent received');

      yield* _mapVerifyPhoneNumberToState(event);
    } else if (event is PhoneCodeSentEvent) {
      print('PhoneCodeSentEvent received');
      yield OtpSentState();
    } else if (event is VerificationCompletedEvent) {
      print('VerificationCompletedEvent received');
      yield VerificationCompleteState(firebaseUser: event.firebaseUser, isVerified: event.isVerified);
    } else if (event is VerificationExceptionEvent) {
      print('VerificationExceptionEvent received');
      yield VerificationExceptionState(message: event.message);
    } else if (event is VerifySmsCodeEvent) {
      print('VerifySmsCodeEvent received');
      yield VerifyingState();
      try {
        AuthResult result =
        await _userRepository.verifyAndLinkAuthCredentials(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: event.smsCode);
        if (result.user != null) {
          yield VerificationCompleteState(firebaseUser: result.user, isVerified: true);
        } else {
          yield OtpExceptionState(message: "Invalid otp!",verificationId: verificationId);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        yield OtpExceptionState(message: "Invalid otp!", verificationId: verificationId);
        print(e);
      }
    } else if ( event is PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeoutEvent){
      yield PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeoutState(verificationId: event.verificationId);
    }

    if(event is SendVerificationCodeEvent) {
      yield*_mapVerificationCodeToState(event);
    }


  }
  Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapVerifyPhoneNumberToState(VerifyPhoneNumberEvent event) async* {
    print('_mapVerifyPhoneNumberToState V2 started');
    yield VerifyingState();



    final phoneVerificationCompleted = (AuthCredential authCredential) {
      print('_mapVerifyPhoneNumberToState PhoneVerificationCompleted');
//      _userRepository.getUser();
      _userRepository.getCurrentUser().catchError((onError) {
        print(onError);
      }).then((user) {
        add(VerificationCompletedEvent(firebaseUser: user, isVerified:  true));
      });
    };
    final phoneVerificationFailed = (AuthException authException) {
      print('_mapVerifyPhoneNumberToState PhoneVerificationFailed');
      print(authException.message);
      add(VerificationExceptionEvent(onError.toString()));
    };
    final phoneCodeSent = (String verificationId, [int forceResent]) {
      print('_mapVerifyPhoneNumberToState PhoneCodeSent');
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      add(PhoneCodeSentEvent());
    };
    final phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout = (String verificationId) {

      // after this print Bloc error is Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close
      print('_mapVerifyPhoneNumberToState PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout');
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      add(PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeoutEvent(verificationId: verificationId));
    };

    await _userRepository.verifyPhone(
        phoneNumber: event.phoneNumber,
        timeOut: Duration(seconds: 0),
        phoneVerificationFailed: phoneVerificationFailed,
        phoneVerificationCompleted: phoneVerificationCompleted,
        phoneCodeSent: phoneCodeSent,
        autoRetrievalTimeout: phoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }


  Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapVerificationCodeToState(SendVerificationCodeEvent event) async* {
    print('_mapVerificationCodeToState started');
    yield VerifyingState();
    try {
      AuthResult result =
      await _userRepository.verifyAndLinkAuthCredentials(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: event.smsCode);
      if (result.user != null) {
        yield VerificationCompleteState(firebaseUser: result.user, isVerified: true);
      } else {
        yield OtpExceptionState(message: "Invalid otp!", verificationId: verificationId);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      yield OtpExceptionState(message: "Invalid otp!", verificationId: verificationId);
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `BlocProvider.of<PhoneAuthenticationBloc>`

Comment: @PietervanLoon In a Button on the `onPressed` callback I perform a check, and if it fails I return a `Dialog` with a button from which `onPressed` I I send the event.
Sorry, I didn't realize some code sample was missing , thanks for making me notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong context when adding the event.
When showing the dialog the widget will be placed in an overlay which is above the bloc provider, so by using the context of the dialog you cannot find the bloc since there is no provider above it.

To fix this name the context of the dialog something else (ie. dialogContext) such that when doing `BlocProvider.of(context)` the context refers to the context of the widget showing the dialog instead of the context of the dialog itself.

Comment: Absolutely! You're right indeed.. I could't see it myself. Thank you so much and welcome to StackOverflow. Nice start . Cheers.